# HttpPostedFileBase returns null

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to upload a single .csv file in ASP.NET MVC. In my .ascx file, I have:

```
        <div>           
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
            &nbsp &nbsp
           <input type="submit" name="btnSubmit" id="btnSubmit" value="Upload" />
        </div>
```

The controller action is:

```
 public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            if (file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/uploads"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
            return View();
        }
```

The problem is that I always get file as Null in the Upload Action. Any suggestions on how to get this working?

Comment: Does the issue happen in IE, FireFox and other browsers or is it isolated to just one browser? With some uploading I've done in IE HttpPostedFileBase works but in Mozilla/Webkit I have to read the file from the Request.InputStream

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you sure you have a

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
<div> bla bla
</div>
</form>
```

?

Edit : 
method="post"

+

```
[HttpPost]
```

on your action

Comment: Yes, I have this:<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/Admin/Home/Upload">